# Mysql joker characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to update in my table all key start by 'example_', in databse i have

```
- id
- example_1
- example_2
- ...
- date
```

php

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET example_*='0'";
$sql = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute();
```

But this solution not work.
Thanks you

Comment: looks like a bad design to have column names like that - which is why you cant use wild cards directly on them

Comment: What is good design for multiple value ? Json ? But i need json_decode, edit and json_encode for each update ?

Comment: hard to answer with out exact details but you probably want a new table with `id | example` then query with joins